# How can I select from table by uuid in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, guid, uuid

I want to select some data from database (MySQL) comparing 'Id' Column.
And It's type is binary(16) .

So, I write query like this but It's not work. Empty dataset returned.
How Can I fix it?

```
select Id, CompanyName from table1 where Id = 'e4816509-dd01-cf1b-65e3-dc43e2a90a01';
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you do a select * from table_name. I am pretty sure, the data is getting truncated as you dint have enough length.
Try to use integers as your primary key.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know if you still need this. But, here's the query.

```
select Id, CompanyName from table1 where Id = x'e4816509dd01cf1b65e3dc43e2a90a01';
```

OR

```
select Id, CompanyName from table1 where Id = 0xe4816509dd01cf1b65e3dc43e2a90a01;
```

!!! note that the dashes from the uuid were removed

Answer (score 3):

try: `SELECT Id, CompanyName FROM table1 WHERE Id= UNHEX('e4816509-dd01-cf1b-65e3-dc43e2a90a01');`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
I used hibernates auto-ddl in Spring to create tables from JPA-entities.
The UUID column created was of type binary(255).

(In mysql, there exist the types binary() and varbinary(), working like char() and varchar()).

For binary(255) the data inserted seems to be extended to 255 bytes.
Comparing these 255 bytes to a 16-byte-UUID didn't work for me.

When I created the exact same table using datatype binary(16) for the UUID, querying with a UUID worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
select Id, CompanyName from
  table1
 where Id = uuid_to_bin('e4816509-dd01-cf1b-65e3-dc43e2a90a01')
```

`uuid_to_bin` for mysql.